# What would be a minimum ICAO Aerodrome Reference Code for C-130?

Tags: airport-design

I was wondering, mostly of military planes are not mentioned by ICAO on its papers (for sure, it is dedicated to civil aviation), but it's common to see military cargo planes operating on Civil Airports in Civil Aprons. I believe that mostly of this military cargo planes are intended to Takeoff/Land with higher loads in a significant short distance with low ACN number (in comparison with civil cargo aircraft).

So, if we consider a C-130H "Hercules" operating in a Civil Airport, what would be a minimum ICAO Aerodrome Reference Code (like 4D, 3D, 2D?
I believe Code Element 2 is a "D" due the wingspan (around 40m) and Outer main gear wheel span of 4.34m.

Comment: Reference codes you mention are introduced by annex 14 and can be found in [Doc 9981](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/bazl/en/home/specialists/regulations-and-guidelines/legislation-and-directives/anhaenge-zur-konvention-der-internationalen-zivilluftfahrtorgani/manuals-zu-icao-annex-14.html) (PANS-ADR).